# jQuery contenteditable - how activate on click

Tags: jquery

When you set a a div contenteditable to true, how can you get it to open as editable textarea without the clicking on the div and rather clicking on a different button on a page?

At the moment I have no idea how to achieve that, thus I didn't try anything.
The only thing which works for editablecontent is when pressing on the div itself, but I would like to set some button which when clicked will act as if you clicked the contenteditable div

Answer (score 6):

I would vote down but I don't have 125 rep. So instead I'll answer, hoping you'll accept my answer, so I can vote down your question :)

Where your code now contains `$(this).attr("contenteditable","true")` remove it. Then add a button to your page with id="someButton". Add some javascript on that button to set the contenteditable attribute to true of the div you actually want to edit, as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#someButton").on("click", function(){
        $("#div-you-actually-want-ID").attr("contenteditable","true");
    });
});
```

Since you have no code and no further explanation, I hope this will help you forward enough to solve your issue.

Comment: You may also want to focus on this new element after you set it to content editable. E.g. $("#div-you-actually-want-ID").focus().